# Update DB through Gridview selected DDL from DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

I have one gridview which is connected through SQL Data source from one table and I have enabled the EDIT and delete columns of gridview. When I'm Editing the value of row, a column is having DDL in Edit mode instead of textbox connected through another SQL datasource.

Once the page loads, after clicking the Edit Row of the Gridview, i'm selecting another value from dropdown and after clicking update it giving me error, can not insert null values into database.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateRoster.aspx.cs" Inherits="E_Scheduler.CreateRoster" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="CSS/Addroster.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="maindiv">




        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#

    CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="username">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                           <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="username" DataValueField="username"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="r_date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("r_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("r_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From" SortExpression="from_time">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("from_time") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("from_time") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To" SortExpression="to_time">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("to_time") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("to_time") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [roster] WHERE [id] = @id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [roster] ([username], [r_date], [from_time], [to_time]) VALUES (@username, @r_date, @from_time, @to_time)" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [username], [r_date], [from_time], [to_time] FROM [roster]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [roster] SET [username] = @username, [r_date] = @r_date, [from_time] = @from_time, [to_time] = @to_time WHERE [id] = @id">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="r_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="from_time" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="to_time" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="r_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="from_time" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="to_time" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [username] FROM [users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send BACK the `SelectedValue` of your dropdownlist:

Use this: `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("username")%>'` as:

```
<EditItemTemplate>                           
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
           DataTextField="username" DataValueField="username" 
           SelectedValue='<%# Bind("username")%>'>
      </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Getting Error as -->DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: What is the data type of your column: "username" ? Does it allows Null ? If yes, Try setting the  AppendDataBoundItems="true" on the dropdownlist and add one NULL value select item to your dropdownlist in EditTemplate  as: 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Choose..." Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Datatype is Varchar and it doesn't allow null values